# Re enable Secure Boot, Screen Goes Blank After Installing NVidia Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, kernel, secure-boot

I had installed NVIDIA Drivers 465.27 on my Ubuntu 20.04 using software updater.
That time, I could not sign the kernel modules via installer as mentioned  [here](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.48/README/installdriver.html#RegisteringTheNda02d), rather I disabled the secure boot option from BIOS and everything worked fine. Drivers are working fine, GPU is detected.

As disabling secure boot might not be a security best practice, I wanted to enable it again but my screen goes blank after booting up. I tried manually signing NVIDIA kernel module in DKMS with the method mentioned in this [Ubuntu blog](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot)

I can see that my **nvidia** modules at `/lib/modules/5.8.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/` are signed as I can see the message `Module signature appended~`. at the end of hex dump. But still if I enable `Secure Boot` option, the screen goes blank after booting. How can I re-enable secure boot in my Ubuntu 20.04? Thank you in advance!